# echo clear multidimensional array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, echo

it seems a simple question but I cannot remember why:

so... I have an array on $_POST and I want to make a echo of that variable:

Im doing this:

```
   function h()
   {
    foreach($_POST as $k => $v ){
   echo $v;

    }
```

Thats fine but I have a problem:

The $POST should be expecting  two or more values, for example:

```
     Array ( [s-armenia] => TRIBUNAL ADMINISTRATIVO DE SUCRE [s-armenia2] => 0 )
```

so.. with my function I get this:

```
   TRIBUNAL ADMINISTRATIVO DE SUCRE 
   0
```

¿How echo my function without the 0?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: this is NOT a multidimensional array

Comment: it is more big than this its only an example

Comment: its not a very good example when it its missing such key information :(

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys for your help, I think about something simple like this and it works:

```
  function h()
 {
 foreach($_POST as $k)
  {
  $p = "/0/";
  $s = "";
  echo preg_replace($p, $s, $k);

  }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($_POST as $k)
{
   echo $k;
}
```

=> $v would be the key (which is 0)
 your array should look like `array(1 => 2, 3 => array(3.1 => 3.2), 4 => 5)`

edit: adding from PHP manual:

```
<?php
$array = array(
    "foo" => "bar",
    42    => 24,
    "multi" => array(
         "dimensional" => array(
             "array" => "foo"
         )
    )
);

var_dump($array["foo"]);
var_dump($array[42]);
var_dump($array["multi"]["dimensional"]["array"]);
?>
```

Comment: I want a clear string without the 0 or any number that indicates the properties of the array.

Comment: you cant have x => y => z, why would you want that? Use two arrays

Comment: Well want it this because that array are from the $_POST and I want to show the chosen post option .

Comment: `foreach($_POST as $value => $key) { $ar_value = array($value => $key); }` can you show your form?